# Берутся ли в кавычки слова "за" и "против"?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Берутся ли в кавычки слова "за" и "против" в предложениях подобного типа: "Я только "за", "Десять человек проголосовали "против", а один воздержался"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В справочнике Розенталя говорится о следующих случаях, когда слова выделяются кавычками: 
1)слова непривычные, малоупотребительные, на которые автор хочет обратить внимание; 2)слова, употребленные в особом, необычном значении; 3)слова, представляющие собой малоизвестные термины; 4)слова устарелые или, наоборот, совсем новые, если подчеркивается эта их особенность; 5)слова, употребленные в ироническом значении; 6)слова, употребленные в условном значении (применительно к ситуации или контексту).

Кавычки при необычно употребляемых словах рассматриваются как *факультативный* знак. Один из основных критериев при употреблении кавычек рассматриваемого типа – «обычность/необычность», или, другими словами, «привычность/непривычность». Но разграничить «привычное» и «непривычное» значения слова зачастую очень трудно. Грамота.ру предлагает руководствоваться следующими правилами при использовании кавычек: 1) ориентироваться на словарные статьи в толковых словарях русского языка: если слово (словосочетание) в них уже зафиксировано, следовательно, значение не является непривычным и кавычки не нужны; 2) учитывать стиль текста, в котором встречаются подобные лексические единицы. Безусловно, наиболее часто их можно встретить в газетных и журнальных текстах, но при этом в «серьезных» СМИ, предлагающих читателям материалы на общественно-политические и социально значимые темы, постановка кавычек при необычно употребляемых словах более уместна, чем, например, в газетах и журналах, ориентированных на молодежную аудиторию и пишущих на «легкие» темы, поскольку при употреблении слова в «непривычном» значении оно чаще имеет разговорную или просторечную окраску. (см. http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=kav)

В вашем случае никакого высокого стиля не наблюдается, так что кавычки, на мой взгляд, можно не ставить.