# "Жаль но войны до скончанья веков и неважно против ты или за." Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

**"Жаль, но войны - до скончанья веков; и неважно, против ты или за."**

Comment: Вы расскажите, в чем сомнения - разберемся, а домашние задания тут обычно не делают  - и не проверяют.

Comment: Сомневаюсь в том, нужна ли точка с запятой; правильно ли слитное написание "неважно";нужно ли взять в кавычки слова "против" и "за".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да,  а вопросы-то хорошие оказались.

> Сомневаюсь в том, нужна ли точка с запятой;

Не думаю, что она строго обязательна, но очевидно, что возможна и уместна.

> 2. Союзами и и да (в значении «и») лишь в том случае, когда они соединяют два предложения, которые без них были бы разделены точкой. (В таких случаях предложения, начинающиеся союзами и, да, являются по характеру связи присоединительными.)

http://gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=tz

> Правильно ли слитное написание "неважно";

Оно факультативно. Возможно и раздельное (причем это не несет какого-то дополнительного смысла), но здесь лучше смотрится именно слитное. При таком написании подчеркивается, что это понятие "неважности", а не просто отрицание важности.

> нужно ли взять в кавычки слова "против" и "за". –

Не обязательно. Если нет какого-то высокого стиля речи, то лучше и не ставить.
Подробнее - здесь.
[Нужны ли кавычки?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Т.е. Ваша фраза в исходном виде вполне пунктуационно правильна, а все три вопроса относятся к факультативным вариантам написания.

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ!

Answer (score 1):

1) Точка с запятой здесь желательный знак, так как он способствует пониманию теста при наличии большого количества знаков препинания в небольшом по объему предложении.

2) Неважно - здесь слитное написание приставки НЕ предпочтительнее. Раздельно "не важно" уместнее писать при наличии противопоставления: не важно это, а важно то.

3) Кавычки не нужны, так как предлоги употреблены в значении существительных.

Из словаря:
ЗА , в знач. сущ. (взвесить все за и против), нареч. (голосовать за), сказ. (я - за, а он против).

Comment: С п а с и б о !