# Оформление прямой речи (частица да)

Tags: прямая-речь

Я скажу да.

Можно ли не оформлять прямую речь в частице "да" и почему, если да?

Comment: Ответ изменён._

Answer (score 1):

Если кто-то действительно скажет это слово, то кавычки нужны. Можно без двоеточия.

Если имеет место другое значение — соглашусь, а не скажу именно это слово, то это устойчивое выражение (фразеологизм) и кавычки не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

По типу *за* или *против*, кавычки для *да* не только не обязательны, но и не нужны, т. к. могут внести скрытый смысл в текст. Об том говориться у Розенталя (см. ответ на нашем сайте: [Берутся ли в кавычки слова "за" и "против"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/%d0%91%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2))

Answer (score 0):

Грамота не даёт однозначных рекомендаций, надо ли брать ***да*** в кавычки или нет. В вашем случае она допускает написание без них:

> **Вопрос № 294099**
>   "Я подумал и сказал да" — нужно ли ставить "да" в кавычки? Заранее спасибо.
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Возможно без кавычек: *сказал да* (=согласился). Но: *сказал твердое «да».*